# Simplepie proxy support

Tags: curl, proxy, rss, simplepie

Is there a simple solution to adding proxy settings on SimplePie? I've tried to look through resources online and there are a bunch of patches. None of them are really clear on what version of SimplePie they use.

I am trying to build an RSS reader for my company and I will need to provide a proxy IP and port to connect to the outside world. Do I need to find another RSS reader or is there actually proxy support in SimplePie?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/abhij89/c7f475cd581e9af9498f4cccf7e2d9f0

Answer (score 2):

For SimplePie 1.3.1

You must do a modification to one of the files: File.php

Line 112, you must add the following line to be able to pass your PROXY:

```
// Patch 
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy_name");
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "proxy_port");
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE );
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "proxy_user:proxy_password");
```

Of course you must replace proxy_name by the server name, proxy_port by the used port, proxy_user by user name (could be of the form "domain\login" when NTLM is used) and proxy_password as password of the user in clear text.

Regards,
Tomolimo

Comment: line `2` should read: `curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "proxy_port");`